# after success function div value back to first value

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<div id="user">username1</div>
<script language="javascript">
$('.button').live('click',function(){ 
    $("#user").html('<img src="loading.gif">');
    $.ajax({
         type: "POST",
         url: "getuserid.php",
         data: "userid="+userid,
         success: function(html){
              $("#user").append(html);
              alert(html);
         }
    });  
});
</script>
```

i have several button  with button class
after i click button with .button class i see appended data to #user (returned from server) but after click alerted message, data in "#user" backed to first value "username1".
why?
if i  remove alert(html) i cant see appended data at all.

Answer (score 0):

We can only guess because you didn't provide much code, but presumably your `.button` element is an actual HTML `<button />` (or worse, an `<input type="button" />`) and it's probably leading to your page being refreshed.

Use `preventDefault` to stop this behaviour:

```
$('.button').live('click',function(e){  
    $("#user").html('<img src="loading.gif">');
    $.ajax(.....);
    e.preventDefault();
 });
```

Comment: thank u f. i have several image with button class. i used your code but my problem is remained.

Comment: @a.v: As I said, we can only guess. Post the relevant HTML. If possible, post a jsfiddle.net snippet so that we can _see_ the problem.

Comment: i cant use jsfiddle  but when i change my code and use $('.button').click(function(){  } instead of live function it works. so problem is with live. when i use exit(); in success into live function  it works too. another thing is i have several .button class and they are ajax loaded.